# Errors in swift

Tags: swift3, enums

I'm new to programming with Xcode/Swift and I am trying to create a match 3 puzzle game but I am getting stuck when trying to create my bricks.
I can't get my brick randomizer to work, as Xcode gives me some error that I can't figure out how to solve.

My class of blocks works, but it´s the enum that gives me error, more specifically the raw value I want of my sprites name randomizer.

I get errors when trying to return a raw value of any block array which either says ambiguous use of operator or when changing to just raw value it says string does not work with raw value.

what am I doing wrong?

```
enum BrickType: uint{

case uknown = 0
case yellowbrick = 1
case redbrick = 2
case orangebrick = 3
case blackbrick = 4
case bluebrick = 5
case tealbrick = 6
case greenbrick = 7
case whitebrick = 8

var spriteName: String{

    let spriteNames = [
        "yellowBrick",
        "blueBrick",
        "greenBrick",
        "orangeBrick",
        "redBrick",
        "whiteBrick",
        "tealBrick",
        "blackBrick"
    ]


    return spriteNames[rawValue - 1]
}

static func random() -> BrickType {
    return BrickType(rawValue: uint(arc4random_uniform(8)) + 1)!
}

}

class Blocks {

var column: Int = 0
var row: Int = 0
let brickType: BrickType
var sprite: SKSpriteNode?

init(column: Int, row: Int, brickType: BrickType) {
    self.column = column
    self.row = row
    self.brickType = brickType
}
```

}

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Int` rather than `uint`, an array cannot be subscripted by `uint`

```
enum BrickType: Int {

...

return BrickType(rawValue: Int(arc4random_uniform(8)) + 1)!
```

---

And as `Brick` is a part of the enum type and 0 is the default value I recommend to name the cases

```
case uknown, yellow, red, orange, black, blue, teal, green, white
```

The raw values are implicitly the same.

Comment: the enum does not work with int. if I change to int I get 50 errors. what I want to return is the sprite names but that does not conform to string when using an array of strings with a raw value .

Comment: Then your question does not show the real code. It's supposed to work with `Int`

Comment: the enum itself works when edited like you say, but that is now the problem. I get an error at the line; Return spriteNames [rawValue - 1], it says ambiguous use of operator, or if I change it to only return[rawValue] it says it cannot subscribe type string to a type of uint A.k.a Uint32

Comment: Please read my answer. You have to use **`Int`** (even in the declaration) not `UInt` or `uint`. And  `[rawValue]` without subtraction is correct since indexes are zero-based.

Comment: now I changes all you said and it gives me an yellow error on the return line; '-' is deprecated: Mixed-type subtraction is deprecated. Please use explicit type conversion.

Comment: This is impossible after changing `uint` to `Int`.

Comment: if I remove the " - 1 " part of return code I get the error again that it cannot subscribe a type string to a type int.

Comment: `Int` with CAPITAL I

Comment: is `return BrickType(rawValue: Int(arc4random_uniform(8)) + 1)!` suppose to be a function?

Comment: @Honey It's the body of the `random()` function. I wanted to show only the lines to be changed.